# How to add italic values in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following df:

```
df <- data.frame(Species = c("C. lupus", "C. latrans", "C. lupaster"),
                 pi = c('0.03', '0.04', '0.02'))
```

and I made a plot with ggplot

```
df %>%
  mutate(Species= fct_reorder(Species, pi )) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Species, y=pi)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="#f68060", alpha=.6, width=.4) +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("") +
  theme_bw() +
  ylab("Nucleotide diversity (π)")
```

How can I write the species names in italic?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face = 3))`:

```
df %>%
  mutate(Species= fct_reorder(Species, pi )) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Species, y=pi)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", fill="#f68060", alpha=.6, width=.4) +
  coord_flip() +
  xlab("") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(face = 3)) +
  ylab("Nucleotide diversity (π)")
```

[image]